# xcode: Image is axb, should be axb

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I'm resizing some images for an ios LaunchImage collection (to create the splash page for an app) and xcode is telling me that one image should be dimensions axb, but that the image is axb:

[image: screenshot]

I'm using 8.2.1 (8C1002). Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this situation?

Comment: I'm a bit confused... Xcode says you need a 750x1334 image, but the image you have is 750x1134 ... Or is something else going on that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Yes, exactly @DonMag. What's odd is that xcode accepts all the other images without warnings--it's just this one size that raises a warning/error...

Comment: Are all the other images *also* the wrong sizes? Or, wait... do you have only the ONE image?

Comment: All images are the right size and are acknowledged as so by xcode with the exception of 750 x 1134, which I take to be the right size, but which causes xcode to bark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm....

Xcode says you need 750 x 1334

Xcode says your image is 750 x 1134

Are you just (whoops?) seeing **1134** and **1334** as the same number?